# CiviCRM API Implementation

Tags: api

How are API's implemented in the CiviCRM Codebase? I have a idea of basic structue user <-> api <-> BAO <-> DAO <-> mysql but I guess there is more to this than just this structure. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you have any specific questions that were not covered in the Developers Guide?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE! The first place to look for this information is in the relevant section of the developers guide at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/

Comment: Thanks Mick for the same!

Answer (score 3):

I just finished writing a man page for this: *[APIv4 Architecture](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v4/architecture/)*

Note that there are currently [2 versions of the CiviCRM API](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v4/differences-with-v3/). APIv3 has been around for years, and APIv4 is fairly new. But they both rely on core BAO classes for writing data, and a query builder for fetching data.